# Having trouble creating JSON payload that contains (world of warcraft) races and the playable classes for each race

Tags: python, api, flask-sqlalchemy, world-of-warcraft

I'm using Python, `sqlalchemy` ORM, Flask, and oauth stuff.
I'll try to specify this as much as possible...

I want to pull information from some online source (API, website, etc.) that will list out the playable races for World of Warcraft and then also have the playable classes for each race. I'm building an API for a final project in a college course and the Blizzard API only lists races and classes separately. It doesn't give me a good way to have the races and then the list of playable classes for each race.

Essentially, I want to be able to return a payload like the following:

```
"races": [
{
    "name": race.name,
    "faction": race.faction,
    "description": race.description,
    "link": url_for('race_info', raceName=race.name)
    "classes: ['warrior', 'paladin', 'hunter']
}
for race in races
]
```

I could just go through and add this stuff manually into my database, but my professor is insisting we pull info from the web and put it directly into our database. He doesn't want us to hardcode anything into our database.

Alternatively, if someone can think of a way for me to take the JSONs I'm receiving from Blizzard's API and somehow use that info to do what I want without just hardcoding everything, I'm open to ideas.

Sorry if I didn't specify my needs enough.

Edit: I was asked for samples of the races and classes JSON. If I print out the results from a request for /race and /class I get the following...

/race ...
{'races': [{'description': 'test', 'faction': 'alliance', 'link': '/race/Human', 'name': 'Human'},... rest of races here

/class ...
{'classes': [{'class name': 'Warrior', 'link': '/class/Warrior', 'power type': 'rage'},... rest of classes here

Comment: Provide a sample of what the `races` and `classes` JSON's look like.

Comment: Do you mean a sample of what the JSON I'm giving to my user looks like or what the JSON I'm getting from the blizzard API looks like?

Comment: the 2nd one: what the JSON from Blizzard's API looks like, since we can't see samples on their site without signing up.

Comment: {
  "races": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "mask": 1,
      "side": "alliance",
      "name": "Human"
    },

Comment: {
  "classes": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "mask": 1,
      "powerType": "rage",
      "name": "Warrior"
    },

Comment: That's what the JSON I get from their API looks like. I can't seem to find anything in their API that lists out the playable races for a class or the playable classes for a race.

Comment: Okay, do all classes belong to each race? (I've not played Warcraft since it was called... _Warcraft_.)

Comment: No, that's the issue I'm running into. So, for instance, if you play a Troll you only have access to the following classes: Death Knight, Druid, Hunter, Mage, Priest, Rogue, Shaman, Warlock, Warrior, Monk. So a troll can't play a paladin or demon hunter. I'm wondering if I could somehow do some web scraping to get this info from another site. This one >>> [link](https://wow.gamepedia.com/Race) <<< has a table showing the classes available for each race, but I'm not sure how I could pull that data out of the web page. I'm new to web scraping.

Comment: If you can't query the classes per race or if the classes don't indicate which races they belong to, then there's no programmatic way to map them together. See [this post](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/bnet/topic/20767749107#post-3) on their forums referring to the `playable-class` API which may give the combinations you need.